# Is placing javascript directly on HTML document deprecated?

Tags: javascript

I am shocked to read the following from [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html#direct):

> Deprecated: Direct JavaScripts
>
> Do not use direct JavaScripts for the reasons explained in section 2C
>   of the book. This section is only maintained for historical reasons.
>
> The simplest method is to place your scripts directly in the page. How
>   to place
>
> ```
> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
> <!--
>
> script goes here
>
> // -->
> </script>
> ```

Based on my understanding reading the article, javascripts are to be included using the `src` attribute on `<script>` tags instead. I don't have [the book](http://www.quirksmode.org/book/) and can't find further references online that says this. Does anyone know whether this is correct or did I misinterpret what it is trying to say?

Comment: In about 30 lines of text there are at least three outdated facts on this page. I would ignore the hell out of it. This page basically explains the world about 5 to 10 years ago.

Comment: it just stating not to use,but it doesn't stated that it is deprecated

Comment: @rid Seems like a bit of a cheap marketing ploy, to be honest. "Don't do this! But you have to buy my book to find out why I'm telling you not to do it."

Comment: "JavaScript includes are not supported by Netscape 2 and Explorer 3.". Nuff said.

Comment: @rajeshkakawat — Look at the first word of the quoted material.

Comment: language attribute in script tag is deprecated and type attribute is optional.

Comment: q̶u̶i̶r̶k̶s̶m̶o̶d̶e̶.̶o̶r̶g̶ **is not the offical source of deprecated information for Web,  W3C - https://www.w3.org/ is**, the closest "informal" is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) which is usually pretty up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPK means that **the section itself is deprecated**. The advice presented there was generally accepted and relevant at the time of publication, but it no longer aligns with current markup languages and best practices:

1. The `language` attribute has been [deprecated since HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-language).
2. In HTML5, the [default value of the `type` attribute is `text/javascript`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element)—thus, it can often be discarded.
3. The HTML comments (`<!--` and `-->`) surrounding the script itself are [a workaround for the IE 2 and Netscape 1 generation of browsers](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html), and have not been required for nearly 20 years.
4. Later he advises that you place scripts in the `head` of your document. This made sense in the days of dial-up, but nowadays it is recommended that outside of a few specific circumstances (e.g. Modernizr, html5shiv) you should [place scripts at the *end* of your document `body`](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-6-move-scripts-bottom-7200.html) to prevent them from blocking rendering and parallel downloads.

### More current advice

[Avoid inlining scripts in general](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-8-javascript-css-external-7205.html) for better maintainability and cacheability. You are still *allowed* to inline scripts, and it may make sense if:

- the script is dynamically generated for just that page; or
- the script is very small, and you can demonstrate a measurable and worthwhile improvement in performance due to [avoiding the additional HTTP request](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS#inlineJS).

Unless otherwise necessary, use the following syntax for inline JS.

**HTML5:**

```html
<script>
    // ...
</script>
```

**HTML 4.01:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    // ...
</script>
```

**XHTML5:**

```html
<script>
//<![CDATA[
    // ...
//]]>
</script>
```

**XHTML 1.x:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    // ...
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra information which is really what I am interested to know.

Answer (score 3):

No HTML specification marks inline JavaScript as deprecated or obsolete.

It is widely regarded as being less than best practise though.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the straight answer. I almost fell off my chair when I first read the article.

Answer (score 1):

It is not deprecated, and it is still used widely.

If you look at this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting it is very well explained why its a bad idea.

The biggest problem i have with it, is that it makes your html pages look stuffed. If you for example have a bit of javascript inline, and a bit of javascript in another file, it is pretty hard to find the right code if you need to change it.

Same goes for inline css. It makes your html files harder to read and understand.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is bad in general, but there would be certain situations where you would need it, like making something hide immediately.

Answer (score 1):

script tag is not deprecated.

The relevant section is called "Deprecated: Direct JavaScripts", and
the note referes to the section's title. Must read:
"Do not use "Direct JavaScripts" recommendations for  tag
syntax. This section is only maintained for historical reasons."

**the section is deprecated**

http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1338952&seqNum=3